# How do I switch on FSAAx4 in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

I knew glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_MULTISAMPLE) will open the multisample antialias, but how do I control the sample quality like x2 or x4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't choose sample quality in pure OpenGL. This is done by platform-specific calls like wglChoosePixelFormat or glxChooseVisual. But if you're using GLUT, these calls are done behind the scenes, so you have only amount of control that GLUT exposes - that's [glutInitDisplayString](http://linux.die.net/man/3/glutinitdisplaystring), see parameter "samples".

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, you'd pass the WGL_SAMPLES attribute with the desired multisampling level to choosePixelFormat. Passing 0 implies a 2x sample quality.

Comment: Then how about Ubuntu linux? I'm using Ubuntu 11.